# SQL Server Merge 2 rows into 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

Is it possible to merge 2 rows into a single row in SSRS 2008?
Each part will have a record for each site

```
+---------------+-------+-------+
|Part Number    |Cost   |Site   |
+---------------+-------+-------+
|1              |2.4    |Site 1 |
|1              |68.8   |Site 2 |
+---------------+-------+-------+
```

Desired Result

```
+-----------+-------+-------+
|Part Number|Site 1 |Site 2 | 
+-----------+-------+-------+
| 1         |2.4    |68.8   |
+-----------+-------+-------+
```

Thank you

Comment: You will need to find about CROSS TAB queries.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you know your site numbers/names will not change dynamically then can use `CASE WHEN`:s

```
SELECT PartNumber,
MAX(CASE WHEN Site=1 THEN Cost ELSE NULL END) AS Site1_Cost,
MAX(CASE WHEN Site=2 THEN Cost ELSE NULL END) AS Site2_Cost
FROM Parts
GROUP BY PartNumber
```

By grouping we eliminated a NULL values...

Here [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/335b6/4) with SQL Fiddle example

Comment: if i want all the records to be shifted not just the max then what should I do

Answer (score 2):

In SSRS to you need to use `MATRIX` report to convert rows into columns without using `PIVOT operator`

Suppose you have a table `SSRSPivot`

```
Create table SSRSPivot
(PartNumber int ,Cost decimal(18,2),Site varchar(max))


Insert into SSRSPivot
values
(1,2.4,'Site 1'),
(1,68.8,'Site 2' )
```

The data is in the below format

```
+---------------+-------+-------+
|PartNumber    |Cost   |Site   |
+---------------+-------+-------+
|1              |2.4    |Site 1 |
|1              |68.8   |Site 2 |
+---------------+-------+-------+
```

Create a new blank report and name it as `PIVOT`.Create a datasource and in the dataset write the query

```
  Select PartNumber ,Cost,Site from SSRSPivot
```

[image]

Drag a `matrix` from the toolbox onto the SSRS designer.For `Rows` select `PartNumber` .For columns select `Site` and for the data select `Sum(Cost)`

[image]

When you do the above step ,you will get the `row` and `column` details like the one below

[image]

Final Result will look like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This type of data transformation is known as a [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Starting in SQL Server 2005, there is a function that can transpose the data into columns for you.

If you have a known number of `Site` values that you want to turn into columns, then you can hard-code the query:

```
select part_number, [Site 1], [Site 2]
from 
(
  select part_number, cost, site
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  sum(cost)
  for site in ([Site 1], [Site 2])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e333/1)

But if you have an unknown number of values, then you will need to use dynamic SQL to generate the column list to be used in the query:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(site) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT part_number,' + @cols + ' 
             from 
             (
                select part_number, cost, site
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(cost)
                for site in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e333/4). Both will give the result:

```
| PART_NUMBER | SITE 1 | SITE 2 |
---------------------------------
|           1 |    2.4 |   68.8 |
```